# CubeCamera as texture for a sphere Geometry => Cube structure way too visible ... React three fiber

Tags: three.js, shader, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I hope this message finds you well

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-goldwasser-yl3sr3?file=/src/App.js

I've been following the last tutorial of Yuri Artiukh on noise (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPBb-0al7Y0&t=561s&ab_channel=YuriArtiukh) to "translate" it in R3F. It's been a blast but i'm confronting one special issue I can't really resolve :

I'm using a CubeCamera to mirror the shader of the background, and it's working fine, the only problem is that the "structure" of the cube is clearly seeable in the sphere. I don't know if it's coming from the fragment shader or the set up of the renderer for the cube camera. Does anyone has any idea how to solve it.

to do so, I use the CubeCamera component from @react-three/drei :

[image]

plus a fresnel shader that you can found here : https://github.com/ebrahma/threejs_div_testing/blob/b5aa918fba0da04e5b78ee6168450945b5630b71/js/three-lib/shaders/FresnelShader.js

To show it clearly, I have that : [image]

I want that :[image]

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hi, I found a way around the problem by tweaking the values in the sphere shader, it is not the exact result I was looking for, making the sphere look more like a marble than a distorted mirror.
updated the code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-goldwasser-yl3sr3?file=/src/App.js